# Replacing a screen door

Tags: doors, outdoor, door-frame, screens

Recently, our patio screen door has begun to show damage and the screen itself has started to peel off of the damaged frame.  We are now looking to replace it.

We measured the door as 36 1/2 inches wide and 79 5/8 inches high. Our problem is that we do not remember what type of screen door this is.

Does anyone know the screen door type and where to find it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by `type`?

Comment: Replace only mesh. Repairs kit is available at hardware store.

Comment: The Manufacturer is not etched in the glass itself?   Examine every surface to find a label.  It looks like Andersen...but I wouldn't bet money on it.

Comment: On a double-glazed panel, the manufacturer's name or product number may also be etched into the frame material _between_ the two glass panels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in a comment, unless the frame itself is damaged, you just replace the screen in the existing frame. I'm guessing that the "damage" in the outside picture is just an odd aberation caused by your camera, or you'd be asking how to repair siding, too! :)

You pull the spline out of the groove and remove the old screen. You *might* be able to reuse the spline, but if you can't they're not expensive.

You lay out the new screen over the door, then, using a spline tool, you push the spline into the groove to hold the screen in place.

The hardest part is keeping the screen nice and smooth so it looks good when you're done. This shouldn't be too difficult, though, if you take your time and employ a helper or two to hold it tight.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you can get by with replacing the screen.  Use a putty knife to remove the door by slipping the wheels at the bottom off the track.  They're spring loaded; lift the whole door up, and then use the putty knife to lift the wheels off the track, while you pull the door towards you, assuming you're in front of the door.  Be gentle, patient and methodical.

There are perhaps a dozen different types and sizes of spline, so take a piece of the old spline to the hardware store.  Use masking tape to keep the new screen squared up and taut.  I like to run the spline tool along the groove and lightly crease the screen before installing the spline.

If you find the door needs replacing, just use the measurement for a replacement.  Maybe measure twice.

Comment: thanks for the additional details on door removal and the point about different spline sizes.